# ¿Cómo puedo comparar mediante un condicional las URL que ha cargado un WebView con otra por defecto?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con Android Studio, tengo un WebView que carga páginas de WordPress, lo que quiero es es que cuando el WebView cargue un mapa de Google se desahabilite cierta opción, para mi caso el SiwpeRefreshLayout, me preguntaba si existe alguna forma mediante un if verificar si la dirección que se carga en el WebView pertenece a Google Maps, no se, tratar la URL como String y con un contains hacer la comparación o algo así.

El código del MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
WebView browser;



@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "ResourceAsColor", "ResourceType"})

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.content_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
    final NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);



    browser= findViewById(R.id.mainWV);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    browser.loadUrl("http://meyb.byethost22.com/index.php/category/destacado/");
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(browser, true);
    }else {
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
    if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pages/html/main.html");
    } else {
        browser = findViewById(R.id.mainWV);

    }

    //SwipeRefresh
  swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    browser.reload();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient () {
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, 
 GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    });

}
```

El código del Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout             
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
layout_height="">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/mainWV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" >

</WebView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: hola Marlon, es recomendable agregar el código que has realizado para ayudarte de una mejor forma, recuerda revisar [ask], ¿Tienes un ejemplo de la url de mapa google que mencionas? saludos

Comment: Listo, la url de google maps no la defino yo, el problema que tengo es que cuando carga el mapa y luego intento navegar por este al deslizar desde arriba se actualiza automáticamente haciendo imposible utilizar el mapa.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes realizar mediante un [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient), definelo a tu `WebView`:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Esta sería la clase `CustomWebViewClient` donde se realizaría la comparación.

En este ejemplo busca si la url contiene `"/maps"`:

```
private class CustomWebViewClientextends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        //Busca si la url que carga contiene "/maps" 
        if(url.contains("/maps")){

         //deshabilita SiwpeRefreshLayout.

        }else{
         view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```